Is $\text{BPP}$ the largest polynomial-time "tractable" complexity class?
An algorithm is in $\text{BPP}$ if it is a) guaranteed to halt in polynomial time, and b) gives the right answer with some probability $p > 0.5$ independent of the input. $\text{BPP}$ is surprisingly resiliant in the sense that many "natural" ways to improve it still give $\text{BPP}$. For instance, instead of "guaranteed" polynomial running time, we can look at "expected" polynomial running time, or "median" polynomial running time, or even that the "0.1th percentile" of running time is polynomial, and we get $\text{BPP}$ either way.
Given these kinds of results, it is natural to ask if there is any way to improve on $\text{BPP}$, or if there is some proof that $\text{BPP}$ is in some sense the "largest possible polynomial-time complexity class" that is actually considered "tractable" for real life use. I should qualify that a bit:

For now let's assume "tractable" does mean polynomial asymptotic running time.
To be tractable, the user must also be able to get the right answer, for any input, with whatever success probability they want.
If the algorithm fails, the failure mode can be anything: it can return the wrong answer, enter into an infinite loop, etc, as long as this is arbitrarily unlikely.
We are talking about standard models of computation only, with access to some random entropy pool. So not $\text{BQP}$.
Reasonable parallel models of computation would be permitted if they can somehow improve on $\text{BPP}$.
We are assuming that $\text{P ≠ NP}$ and similar things.
We are interested in decision problems only.

You will note that I've left out how we are evaluating the running time when it's a random distribution, and it's because every single thing I can think of so far has led to $\text{BPP}$ regardless. So, given these criteria, is $\text{BPP}$ the best possible, or is there any strictly larger complexity class worth studying?

Are you focused on worst-case guarantees, i.e. the algorithm must satisfy your criteria on every input instance?

Are you only interested in decision problems, or also function problems?

Yes, it must succeed with arbitrarily high probability on every input instance. I was mostly interested in decision problems but am curious what the situation is with function problems as well.

With function problems, you can ask about problems that admit polynomial-time approximations instead of exactly correct answers.

The two main candidates are BPP (randomized computation) and BQP (quantum computation).  No one knows yet whether quantum computers will feasible, but if they are, BQP is a good candidate for modeling tractable computations.
In cryptography, many frameworks treat P/poly algorithms (i.e., algorithms with advice) as potentially tractable.  More specifically, to show that a problem is intractable, they try to prove there is no P/poly algorithm, which is an even more meaningful result (it implies there is no BPP algorithm as a trivial consequence).  However it's also known that P/poly is too broad (e.g., it includes algorithms for undecidable problems), so P/poly is not a good candidate for capturing tractable computations.

OK. So are you saying that, for non-quantum computation, there is nothing larger than BPP considered tractable today at all?

@MikeBattaglia, nothing that I know of.
